# How to automatically find out about updates to a given Ubuntu package in given releases?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I am maintaining my own version of a popular Ubuntu package (vips) in my PPA for a handful of releases (20.04, 20.10). How can I automatically find out when Ubuntu maintainers release an updated version of this package to any of the releases (i.e. security update, bug fix, etc)?

Is there a way to get email notifications? Is there any way to programmatically subscribe to updates so e.g. I could have a cron job that checks for updates and runs a command automatically?

And to the point, is it possible to get notifications only for the given releases (20.04 and 20.10), not others?

Comment: The two releases you give will be different. Groovy hasn't yet become 20.10, thus SRUs aren't required to be filed, SRU's being easy to detect if you add yourself to the ML for bug reports for packages. Add the filter to detect an SRU and you've got a pretty good clue for released *stable* packages anyway (non-development releases).  There's likely better ways, but that's how I see most new release packages in my inbox.  (*As I don't look out for them, I've no need for took for anything better*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly easy, consistent, maintainable way is to parse the output of `rmadison`.

```
~$ rmadison libvips-tools
 libvips-tools | 7.26.3-1build1 | precise/universe | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libvips-tools | 7.38.5-2       | trusty/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libvips-tools | 8.2.2-1        | xenial/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libvips-tools | 8.4.5-1build1  | bionic/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 libvips-tools | 8.9.1-2        | focal/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 libvips-tools | 8.10.2-1       | groovy/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

rmadison is a Python3 script included in the `devscripts` package.

For example, you could compare today's rmadison pull to yesterday's stored copy. If there is a difference, the script sends you an e-mail.

You can easily tell that this  particular lib has had zero post-release updates in any currently-supported release of Ubuntu -- none of the packages are in the XX-update pocket.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 versions:

1. you can write a script that interogates the right url on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ (like: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mousepad) and grabs from there the info. This could be written pretty easy in python.
2. you can write a (bash)script that checks directly in `apt` if the package updated. Like: `apt show package-name | grep Version`. To suppress the warning for this command adapt it like this: `apt show package-name 2>/dev/null | grep Version`